Check if ASCII/ text file is locked or being written
The title is pretty self-explanatory.
The commonly used method:
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    try
    {
        using(FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}

Above code does not work with ASCII-text files. I made a test with a Python code that writes to a text file continuously and in fact, the method returned FALSE (not locked) while in reality, some other application was using the file to write on it.
I can check with a method if the file changes over a short period, but this would be very inefficient if iterated over many files (i.e. 500ms over 1000 files would be 8 minutes wait).
One approach that actually works is to try to do File.Move() and see if it returns an exception. If so, the file is busy. I don't like this approach because in case of problems, it could damage the file since it's actually doing an operation on the file itself.
This would be the implemented method
public bool IsFileLocked(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        string tempFilePath = filePath + ".tmp";
        File.Move(filePath, tempFilePath);
        File.Move(tempFilePath, filePath);
        return false; // File is not locked
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true; // File is locked
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return true; // File is locked or access is denied
    }
}


It's not clear if you actually intend to do anything with the file in question. If it's just a matter of knowing whether a file is being modified without polling, then you can use a FileSystemWatcher class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-8.0
